# Determine if an object is a DateTime and not null as a condition within ternary

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

I have an array of objects:

> object[] myArray

This array can contain int, string, DateTime data types and so on.

Now I am trying to check if an object within myArray is of type DateTime and not null so I perform below ternary:

```
string strDate = myArray[pos] != null && myArray[pos].GetType() is typeof(DateTime) ? Convert.ToDateTime(myArray[pos]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : string.Empty;
```

But I get below error starting from typeof(DateTime):

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: Just try to use `is DateTime`. DateTime is a type already

Comment: Or make it shorter: `string strDate = (myArray[pos] is DateTime date) ? date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"):"";`

Comment: @Fabjan If I change typeof(DateTime) to just simply DateTime I get error: "The given expression is never of the provided type ('System.DateTime')

Comment: Get rid of `GetType` if you use `is`.

Comment: @Ralph Because you check if the type `Type` is a `DateTime`, which is always false. Try `myArray[pos] is DateTime` instead

Comment: @CShark myArray[pos] is DateTime works

Comment: @mjwills This is an old project. Currently  we are planning to move to Visual Studio 2019 community

Comment: You should do that sooner (i.e. today) rather than later. There is no good reason to stay on VS 2013. Already you've cost other developers more than half an hour of time coming up with 'old' ways to make the code compile. That is a considerable ongoing cost. Bite the bullet and upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below approach will work on old C# compilers. I'd strongly suggest moving to VS 2019 though. Your life will become much easier...

```
var bob = myArray[pos] as DateTime?;
string strDate = bob == null ? string.Empty : bob.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`is`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type-pattern) operator like

Solution with C#7 pattern matching feature

```
string strDate = (myArray[pos] is DateTime date) ? date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"): string.Empty;
```

Comment: This does not work, I get error after DateTime in date variable saying: expected ')' I am using NET4.5 and Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Your second answer not works at all. I need to apply Convert.ToDateTime prior to apply .ToString

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call to `Convert.ToDateTime` as you've already done a check to ensure that the object is a `DateTime`. Also, instead of using the ternary operator you can use the new `switch` expression along with some pattern matching:

```
string stDate = myArray[pos] switch
{
    DateTime d => d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
    _          => string.Empty
};
```

Comment: Good answer for the c#8 crowd.

Comment: I forgot to say that I am using Visual Studio 2013